# what is the most performance way to remove duplicate data of PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

I have a table more than 1000000 rows, I am remove the duplicate data from PostgreSQL 13 using this SQL:

```
delete from sentence 
where ctid not in (
    select min(ctid) 
    from sentence 
    group by sentence_zh
)
```

but the SQL is too slow, and execute take too much time. I have already created an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX sentence_zh_idx
ON sentence (sentence_zh);
```

what should I do to remove the duplicate data in this table more quickly? BTW, this is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sentence (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    word_id int8 NOT NULL,
    sentence_en varchar NOT NULL,
    sentence_zh varchar NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    word varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sentence_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX index_dict_word_id ON public.sentence (word_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sentence_en_uniq ON public.sentence (sentence_en,word);
```

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769694)

Comment: Do you have any idea how many duplicates there would be?

Comment: I think the duplicate may be less than 3000. @GerardH.Pille

Comment: Then the delete is best, as in the solution given above.